# How to marshal a multiline string to yaml value

Tags: parsing, go, yaml, multilinestring

I have a struct

```
type Products struct {
    Name    string
    Version string
    Description     string
}
```

holding a multiline string constant as the value for `Description` field, the constant is as follows

```
const DEFAULT_DESCRIPTION = `Please add the description here without removing the literal block (|)
    Sample description will be as follows,
    Fixes for the following in rabbitmq transport
    (i)   Channel not closing issue in rabbitmq publisher
    (ii)  Performance improvements to the transport by introducing a channel pool (configurable) and parameterising queue and exchange creation.
    (iii) Allow configuring connection factory by name in target url`
```

Then I use the package `gopkg.in/yaml.v2` for marshaling the above struct (which contains the above constant as a value for its field) as follows

```
data, err = yaml.Marshal(updateDescriptorV3)
```

and write the generated `yaml` content to a file using `os.file.Write()`
But in the `yaml` file generated above an additional `-` exists after literal_block symbol (`|`) What I am doing wrong?

```
  description: |-
Please add the description here without removing the literal block (|)
Sample description will be as follows,
Fixes for the following in rabbitmq transport
(i)   Channel not closing issue in rabbitmq publisher
(ii)  Performance improvements to the transport by introducing a channel pool (configurable) and parameterising queue and exchange creation.
(iii) Allow configuring connection factory by name in target url
```

What needs to be done to get the above constant as a literal_block in `yaml` as follows?

```
  description: |
Please add the description here without removing the literal block (|)
Sample description will be as follows,
Fixes for the following in rabbitmq transport
(i)   Channel not closing issue in rabbitmq publisher
(ii)  Performance improvements to the transport by introducing a channel pool (configurable) and parameterising queue and exchange creation.
(iii) Allow configuring connection factory by name in target url
```

Comment: So `updateDescriptorV3` is an instance of `Products`?

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/134204). YAML is the opposite of simple. There are 9 ways to write multi-line strings. From that answer `|-: "strip": remove the line feed, remove the trailing blank lines.`.

Comment: Before anyone starts downvoting, do *you* remember the entire YAML spec? Really? It's larger than XML, with different libraries using different rules to serialize. [YAML: Probably not so great after all](https://arp242.net/weblog/yaml_probably_not_so_great_after_all.html).

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya it's perfectly OK to be surprised by YAML, even experts can't remember every single cryptic combination. In fact, the author of the linked answer had to edit the answer 3 times at least just for multiline strings `There are 5 6 NINE (or 63*, depending how you count) different ways`. The answer has 35 revisions

Comment: You might also want to read my article on YAML quoting: http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2018/03/strings-in-yaml---to-quote-or-not-to-quote.html

Answer (score 3):

It is working properly.  Your multi-line string does not end in a newline, so it is necessary for the YAML to strip the newline when it is parsed. That is precisely what the `|-` does.

If you really want `|` instead, just add a newline to the end of your input string, but be aware of the functional difference.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/13860) for a complete explanation of the various ways to include multi-line strings in YAML.

Comment: That answer is actually used as an [example of YAML's complexity](https://arp242.net/weblog/yaml_probably_not_so_great_after_all.html): `For example did you know there are nine ways to write a multi-line string in YAML with subtly different behaviour?

Yeah :-/`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You won't find me defending YAML. I don't need to be convinced it's over complex.

Comment: just a coincidence - the article resurfaced yesterday in twitter discussions about config formats. I just realized it linked to *that* answer as an example of its complexity

Comment: I found this discussion useful. I was trying to figure out why my yaml output didn't split onto multiple lines in some cases. Turns out I needed to remove trailing spaces on some lines that some tools had left in their output. Easy with a rexexp ReplaceAllLiteralString - but it does require some figuring out from time to time.